# JSON portion is not load when page is load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

can someone tell me how to make and call my own jquery functions?

take this example code:-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/storylist/",
            function (data) {
                $.each(data.stories, function (i, item) {
                    $row = item.title;
                    $('#storylist tr:last').after("<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.date + "</td><td>" + item.title + "</td><td></td><td>" + item.priority + "</tr>");
                    if (i == 3) return false;
                });
            });

        $("#refresh").click(function (event) {
            alert("yay u clicked refresh!");
            $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/storylist/",
                function (data) {
                    $.each(data.stories, function (i, item) {
                        $row = item.title;
                        $('#storylist tr:last').after("<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.date + "</td><td>" + item.title + "</td><td></td><td>" + item.priority + "</tr>");
                        if (i == 3) return false;
                    });
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

you see the JSON call and code to edit the table is reproduced 2 times. my intention is for the JSON portion to run once when page is loaded, and each time when the user clicks the refresh link. if I go ahead with the current code, obviously it would be a major PITA in maintaining it.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to wrap the JSON function into another function:

```
function JSONrequest(){
     $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/storylist/",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.stories, function(i,item){
                $row = item.title;
                $('#storylist tr:last').after("<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.date + "</td><td>" + item.title + "</td><td></td><td>" + item.priority + "</tr>");
            if ( i == 3 ) return false;
          });
        });

}

$(document).ready(function(){JSONrequest()});
$("#refresh").click(function(){JSONrequest()});
```

Now when you call the JSONrequest function you always execute the same block of code

Comment: Why bother with "function(){JSONrequest()}" ?? Why not just "JSONrequest" ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to simply declare your own function — an ordinary JavaScript function — and pass that function to the `.click()` method and call it from `.ready()`:

```
function requestStories() {
    $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/storylist/",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.stories, function(i,item){
                $row = item.title;
                $('#storylist tr:last').after("<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.date + "</td><td>" + item.title + "</td><td></td><td>" + item.priority + "</tr>");
            if ( i == 3 ) return false;
          });
        });
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#refresh").click(requestStories);
    requestStories();
});
```

Alternatively, if that `.click()` handler is **only** doing the JSON request, you can simply call `.click()` immediately after giving it the function to cause it to run.  For example:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#refresh").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/storylist/",
            function(data){
              $.each(data.stories, function(i,item){
                    $row = item.title;
                    $('#storylist tr:last').after("" + item.id + "" + item.date + "" + item.title + "" + item.priority + "");
                if ( i == 3 ) return false;
              });
            });
        }); 
        return false;
    }).click();
});

Notice that extra `.click()` at the end.  That means, "Now that I've provided you a function to run when `#refresh` is clicked, pretend `#refresh` was clicked.  Keep in mind that this will run **all** code associated with such a click, so this is valid only if this function is the only thing you intend to run.